# Unknown 2-Pin Wire to Wire Connector Type, JST?

Tags: identification, connector

I bought a used Target/Threshold brand "Cheers" sign, however the power supply was missing.

The power supply was almost certainly a small battery pack. I am unsure about the operating voltage but I think it might be 5V. The lights use Edison/screw-in sockets with LED bulbs.

The sign has three strings of lights joined in series. The strings of lights use the same connector. The last connector, a pin connector/female, is where the power supply would connect. The connector is a small rectangular 2-pin wire to wire connector. It looks like this.
[image: 1 x 2 Pin Header]
1 x 2 Pin Header
[image: 1 x 2 Pin Connector "Top"]
1 x 2 Pin Connector "Top"
[image: 1 x 2 Pin Connector "Bottom"]
1 x 2 Pin Connector "Bottom"

The most distinctive feature of the connector it the 2 raised half arrows on the "bottom" of the pin connector.

I do not have experience with electronic projects, but even I know I have seen it before. I just can not place it. After a good bit of searching I thought it was a type of JST connector. Unfortunately I could not find it on their website under either wire to wire or LED connectors.

The dimensions of the pin connector/female are as follows.

- Width 5.65 mm
- Height 4.75 mm
- Depth 7.15 mm
- Pitch @2.2 - 2.5 mm

My caliper blades are too big to fit inside the shroud around the pins to get an accurate measurement of the pitch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: * I am unsure about the operating voltage but I think it might be 5V* - then you must also be unsure about whether it was fed from a constant current source. LEDs normally are.

Comment: Just cut it off and apply a connector of your liking?However if it used a battery pack, it most likely is not 5V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a JST XH connector housing, Digikey part number 455-2266-ND

You can view a 3D model here:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/XHP-2/555485?s=N4IgTCBcDaICwFYEFoxgGzuQOQCIgF0BfIA

If you look at page 2 of the XH datasheet:

https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eXH.pdf

there's this drawing of the housing:

[image]

For the XHP-2 the dimensions of A, B and C are:

[image]

and this aligns with your measurements.